# PROLOG: Trying to get around predsort deleting duplicate objects

Tags: sorting, prolog

I'm trying to make it so predsort wont delete any duplicate objects that I have, and I think I know the logic in it but I can't seem to get it to work. I've been trying to call previous predicates that sort by another item when a duplicate is found but im getting errors when I try this.

```
process(3, X) :-
    nl,
    sort(X, Q),
    show_records(Q),
    nl, nl, menu(Q).

process(4, X) :-
    nl,
    predsort(sortName,X,Q),
    show_records(Q),
    nl, nl, menu(Q).

sortName(T, [_,E,_], [_,R,_]) :-
    (compare(T, E, R)
      ->process(3, X)

      ).


process(5, X) :-
    nl,
    predsort(sortGrade,X,Q),
    show_records(Q),
    nl, nl, menu(Q).

sortGrade(T, [_,_,E], [_,_,R]) :-
    (compare(T, E, R)
      ->process(4,X)
      ).
```

Process 3 sorts by the first value in the sublist, 4 the second one, and 5 the last. I'm trying to make it where when 5 finds a duplicate it'll go to 4, and from 4 to three if need be.

Comment: I've found out how to fix it, I don't know if it is possible to answer my own question so I'll do it here. Here's a link to the code in pastebin : http://pastebin.com/GTQnK5Yh

I just had to change it in the functions to be an OR statement, saying that it could either be equal and not worry about sorting two equal values, or they weren't equal and continue as normal.

Comment: You can answer your own question, and even accept it. Free points. :) BTW, in Prolog, it's *predicate* not *function*. That's why the SWI prolog `predsort/3` isn't called `funcsort/3`. ;)

Comment: Thanks man, yeah my friends give me flack for calling them functions haha. I have such low "rep" I can't answer my question for another 8 hours. So I'll try to do it in the morning. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer anyway, even if you spotted you're own solution, since it's not clear to me if ditto solution matches with mine.

What I mean: time ago I wrote my own predmsort/3 (predating in obvious mode the terminoloy of sort/msort) for exactly the same reason you have reported.

Time passed before I realized that there was a **much** better solution to my problem:

just **never** return =.

That is, so simple...